# Problems with inheritance using Less?

Tags: css, less

I tried to implement the following in less:

```
nav > ul > li:first-child
```

using:

```
nav {   
      ul {
          li:first-child {
```

However the result was:

```
nav ul li:first-child
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two CSS results and also tell me how I can use less to get the result "nav > ul > li:first-child"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is called child combinator.

It selects the "direct successor/child" which is exactly one level below it's parent while the normal style selects all child elements below the parent.

```
<div id="level-1">
  <div id="level-2">
     <div class="level-3"></div>
     <div class="level-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

#level-1 > div{} /* <- matches #level-2 div */
#level-1 div{}   /* <-matches #level-2 and both .level-3 divs */
```

for clarification i added a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fug5e/)**.

as for sass you can use:

```
#level-1{
    > div{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal operation in CSS is "descentant of". That's what less gives you when you don't state a different relationship. Like in this case, "child of":

```
nav {   
    > ul {
        > li:first-child {
```

Or, "following sibling":

```
nav {   
    + ul {
        + li:first-child {
```